# iPhone Leaks not showing trace

Tags: iphone, xcode, memory-leaks

I am running my iPhone App on the simulator and looking for leaks using instruments. The problem is that the trace is not sensible. It does't show any of my code or label any of the system calls. It's all just numbers.

[alt text http://davidbeckblog.com/wp-content/uploads/Screen%20shot%202010-01-01%20at%2010.01.04%20AM.png](http://davidbeckblog.com/wp-content/uploads/Screen%20shot%202010-01-01%20at%2010.01.04%20AM.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Which SDK are you targeting? If you build for 3.0, I believe the symbols don't get displayed. Switching to 3.1 got the symbols displaying for me.

Answer (score 1):

You need to run a Debug build for the traces to be symbolicated.